# vertical scroll in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm beginner in Pyqt and I'd like to add a vertical scroll to my listbox. Somebody can help me?
I appreciate your help.

```
self.lres = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
self.lres.move(190,220)
self.lres.resize(780,460)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QListWidget` already comes with a vertical scroll bar. By default it will only appear when the contents are too big to display in full. If you want the scroll bar to always be visible you can use [`setVerticalScrollBarPolicy()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#verticalScrollBarPolicy-prop)

```
self.lres.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
```